# Regular expression pattern fails

Tags: .net, regex

I have this pattern

```
"^((?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#@$])).{4,10}$"
```

And it seem doing its job checking existence of letter, digit and a special character

Now, I want to add a twist - I want first character to be a letter or digit. And this is not working

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#@$])).{4,10}$"
```

what is not working is - I can type 11 characters instead of 10.

I admit, so far I only checked it  [on this website, not in code](http://regex101.com/). What do I need to do?

Comment: How many chars did you want to allow?

Comment: Your pattern matches 11 characters because `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches one, and `.{4,10}` matches another ten, for a total of 11.

Comment: @Rawing I was sort of trying to group them together and get 4-10 in the end. Obviously it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, making 3-9 instead of 4-10 works good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your regex to,

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#@$])[A-Za-z0-9].{3,9}$
                                            |--------| |
                                            | 1+3=4    |
                                            -----------|    
                                              1+9=10
```

This would allow atleast four characters and atmost 10 characters.

Your pattern matches `11` characters because `[a-zA-Z0-9]` at first takes a character. So you need to specify the range(after the first character) from 3 to 9 so that it would match atleast 4 and atmost 10.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mL4sH7/1)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Moving `[A-Za-z0-9]` to the start of the pattern (like OP did) would increase the performance, would it not?

Comment: Why is it working in the end `^([a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#@$])).{3,9}$` and the back of pattern like yours?

Comment: @T.S.: Because he changed `.{4,10}` to `.{3,9}`. Where you put `[A-Za-z0-9]` doesn't matter.